# Flutter Stack Alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to stack two items but in a custom manner

Required:[image: This is what is looks like now]
Current: [image: This is what I want]

This is code I have now

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
          key: _reservationMadeNotificationIconKey,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

I know I can achieve it by setting a custom size and padding to the second icon, but that won't scale when device size is different, as I want the icon to scale based on the device.

How can I achieve in a way so that it works on all device sizes.

Comment: Problem is your icon is too big. Change your `size` property from the `Icon` widget and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to achieve the same result without having a fixed size and padding, to ensure it can scale as well ?

Comment: Using `Stack` for that isn't probably the best solution. Nevertheless yes, you can always check your constrains with `MediaQuery` or by using a `LayoutBuilder` and work it from there.

Comment: What would a better solution instead of stack or layout builder ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Positioned` to control the position of the widgets inside the stack.

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
        Icon(
           Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
           key: _reservationMadeNotificationIconKey,
           color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Positioned(
           bottom: 3.0,
           child: Icon(
             Icons.check,
             color: Colors.red,
             size: 12.0,
           ),
        ),
   ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to achieve the same result without having a fixed size and padding, to ensure it can scale as well.